# how to call toast from another class in android

Tags: android

i want to call toast from another class's method

i have MainActivity.java

```
package cZ.example.z;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void p(View v){

        newclass  inst = new newclass();
        inst.mmm();


    }

}
```

where p is button1 (ie. android:onClick)

and newclass.java

```
package cZ.example.z;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class newclass extends Activity {

    public void mmm(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

when i clock button1 (p) my app force close but i want to show toast from another class method when click button

any solution

Comment: Why is newclass extending Activity?

Comment: otherwise toast getApplicationContext() gives error :(

Comment: OFFTOPIC: Is it just me or dose questions with bad spelling get downvotes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See below code:

```
public class Utils{

         public static void showToast(Context mContext,String message){
             Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
}
```

and call this method from when ever you want like -

```
Utils.showToast(activity, "hello");
```

hope i m hellpfull to you.

Comment: Don't know who voted this down, but I voted it back up, it's probably the best answer one can expect with such a bad question...

Comment: @radioactive what the problem you get??

Comment: @2Dee dont know who!! but some one is voted down my every answer since yesterday.

Comment: Utils.showToast();  it gives error saying add argument to match showText i added still errors

Comment: This is the correct way. The utility class should not extend an Activity. +1

Comment: @radioactive when a proposed answer doesn't work, you should specify why, and the same goes for your question, which I voted the question down for lack of stacktrace ... I edited the answer to show you how to use the given method.

Comment: would it be possible to give an activity as default for variable mContext? (kotlin)