# Displaying Toast message

Tags: android, android-toast

I'd like to generate a Toast from a class that does not have a View inflated from it.
I have 3 classes in my program. These are:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent screenIntent = new Intent(this, Screen.class);
    this.startActivity(screenIntent);

StartVoiceRecognition StartVoiceRecognitionChild = new StartVoiceRecognition();
    StartVoiceRecognitionChild.makeToast();
    }
}
```

,

```
public class Screen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen);
    //species field
    tvSpecies = this.findViewById(R.id.textboxSpeciesxml);
    tvSpecies.setText(MainActivity.szSpecies);
    ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StartVoiceRecognition extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public void makeToast(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toast content here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The Toast in StartVoiceRecognition class causes the layout in Screen class to be corrupted. How do I put a Toast in StartVoiceRecognition so this does not happen?

Comment: can you post the error logs ?

Comment: huh? The Toast in StartVoiceRecognition class causes the layout in Screen class to be corrupted.what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to call toast from another class in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762047/how-to-call-toast-from-another-class-in-android)

Put this method in another class. Usually we put this common methods in a package called Utils, then, you can use it wherever you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
StartVoiceRecognition.makeToast(this, "This is a Toast msg.");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StartVoiceRecognition extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
public static void makeToast(Context mContext,String message){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```